# Swift - remove cell from TableView after Button-Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in my project I have a `UITableView`. The `cells` inside of that contains among other things a `UIButton` which acts like a "check-box", so the user can tick of a task.

My question: How can I delete a `cell` after the user presses the `UIButton` inside of it?

This is my `customCell` :

```
import UIKit

class WhishCell: UITableViewCell {

    let label: UILabel = {
       let v = UILabel()
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 23)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.font = v.font.withSize(23)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

        let checkButton: UIButton =  {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
//        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
//        v.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxUnchecked"), for: .normal)

        return v
    }()



        public static let reuseID = "WhishCell"

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")}

        override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

            self.backgroundColor = .clear

            // add checkButton
            self.contentView.addSubview(checkButton)
            self.checkButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            self.checkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            self.checkButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
            self.checkButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
            self.checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            // add label
            self.contentView.addSubview(label)
            self.label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true
            self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true



        }

        @objc func checkButtonTapped(){
            self.checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"), for: .normal)
            self.checkButton.alpha = 0
            self.checkButton.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.checkButton.alpha = 1
                self.checkButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `tableView` and the `indexPath` within the cell with this extension:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return (next as? UITableView) ?? (parentViewController as? UITableViewController)?.tableView
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

With the help of this other extension:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

So then you can delete the cell as usual:

```
tableView!.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
```

<sub>**Note that** the **tableView** should be responsible for managing cells.</sub>

Comment: it doesn't recognize `parentViewController`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the other helper extension. Updated.

Comment: I am having troubles implementing this. My `UITableView` is inside my `WishlistTableViewController` class. What do I have to change in your code?

Comment: You don't need to change anything at all! these are extensions and extends every `UIView` and `UITableViewCell` you are using. Nothing else matters. 

Comment: Just implement the two extension and boom, you have access to `tableView` and `indexPath` inside the tableViewCell it self.

Comment: It doesn't work :( As soon as I click it it stops and throws a " SIGABRT" error ..

Comment: `SIGABRT` error is for some other issue. Tell me the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203349/discussion-between-dieglueckswurst-and-mojtaba-hosseini).

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the cell and setting the button selector all you need to set button tag  and selector like this:

```
self.checkButton.tag = indexPath.row
self.checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and make change this in selector:

```
@objc func checkButtonTapped(sender : UIButton){
   let index = sender.tag
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [index], with: .automatic)  

   //Add all your code here..


  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't set `checkButton.Tag = indexPath.row` because I can not access `indexPath.row`  inside my `cell-Class`

Answer (score 0):

A *swifty* way is a callback closure.

In the cell add a property

```
var callback : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
```

In the action call the callback and pass the cell

```
@objc func checkButtonTapped(){


    ...     
    callback?(self)
}
```

In the controller in `cellForRowAt` assign a closure to the callback property

```
cell.callback = { cell in
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
    // insert here a line to remove the item from the data source array.
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) 
}
```

This native Swift solution is much more efficient than assigning tags, *objective-c-ish* target/action or cumbersome *view hierarchy math*.

Answer (score 0):

Change your checkButtonTapped whit this

```
@objc func checkButtonTapped() {
        self.checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"), for: .normal)
        self.checkButton.alpha = 0
        self.checkButton.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.checkButton.alpha = 1
            self.checkButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

        if let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)
            tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath!)
        }
    }
```

And add the next method to your UITableViewDelegate implementation

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            print("Deleted")

            self.texts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```