# UITableViewCell shows the wrong image while images load

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have `UITableView` that lists social media posts with images in them. 
Once all the post details have loaded and the images cached it looks great but while it loads it *often* shows the wrong image with the wrong post.

I have been struggling and coming back to this issue for months. I don't think it is a loading issue it almost looks like iOS dumps the image an any old cell until it finds the right one but honestly I'm out of ideas.

Here is my image extension that also takes care of the caching:

```
    let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()

    extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        self.image = UIImage(named: "loading")

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        //No cache, so create new one and set image
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)

                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            })

        }).resume()
    }

}
```

And this is a shortened version of my `UITableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let postImageIndex = postArray [indexPath.row]
    let postImageURL = postImageIndex.postImageURL

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedItem", for: indexPath) as! FeedItem
    cell.delegate = self

    cell.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(postImageURL)
    cell.postTitle.text = postArray [indexPath.row].postTitle
    cell.postDescription.text = postArray [indexPath.row].postBody

    return cell
}
```

FeedItem Class includes prepareForReuse() and looks like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.delegate = nil
    self.postHeroImage.image = UIImage(named: "loading")
}
```

EDIT: Here is my method for retrieving data from Firebase:

```
func retrievePosts () {

    let postDB = Database.database().reference().child("MyPosts")

    postDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotValue =  snapshot.value as! Dictionary <String,AnyObject>

        let postID = snapshotValue ["ID"]!
        let postTitle = snapshotValue ["Title"]!
        let postBody = snapshotValue ["Description"]!
        let postImageURL = snapshotValue ["TitleImage"]!

        let post = Post()

        post.postTitle = postTitle as! String
        post.postBody =  postBody as! String
        post.postImageURL = postImageURL as! String

        self.configureTableView()
    }
}
```

Comment: And yet supplying a table view with downloaded images is a completely solved well explained matter on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Out of curiosity , why dont you use Kingfisher? I have had similar problem in the past and someone suggested Kingfisher and i started using it. After that never had this problem. (I know this is NOT a solution but more like a workaround)

Comment: @Brewski Hope you are ding well. Are you using prepareForReuse in FeedItem Class???

Comment: I hope PrepareForReuse will solve your problem.

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz I do use prepareForReuse in the FeedItem Class, I added it to my question. But it doesn't help.

Comment: @matt, all the other questions on Stack Overflow deal with different issues such as loading the wrong image consistently or not caching the images.

Comment: @Brewski have you tried? override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    self.postHeroImage.image = nil
}

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz yes I have tried it but also doesn't work.

Comment: hey @Brewski try third party library  `Kingfisher` . if you are putting every cell right detail then it must be issue with your image saving function. let me it does not help

Comment: @Vasucd Hi there, no I haven't - I will do it as a last resort - but I'm trying to solve this problem natively. It doesn't make sense to me that this is a problem when I have done everything "by the book" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UITableView` only uses a handful of cells (~ the max number of visible cells on screen) when displaying a collection of items, so you'll have more items than cells. This works because of the table view reusing mechanism, which means that the same `UITableViewCell` instance will be used for displaying different items. The reason why you are having problems with the images is because you aren't handling the cell reusing properly.

In the `cellForRowAt` function you call:

```
cell.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(postImageURL)
```

While you scroll the table view, in different invocations of `cellForRowAt` this function will be called for the same cell, but (most probably) displaying the content of different items (because of the cell reusing).

Let's X be the cell you are reusing, then these are roughly the functions that will be called:

```
1. X.prepareForReuse()
// inside cellForRowAt
2. X.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(imageA)

// at this point the cell is configured for displaying the content for imageA
// and later you reuse it for displaying the content of imageB
3. X.prepareForReuse()
// inside cellForRowAt
4. X.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(imageB)
```

When the images are cached, then you will always have 1, 2, 3 and 4 in that order, that's why you don't see any issues in that case. However, the code that downloads an image and set it to the image view runs in a separate thread, so that order isn't guaranteed anymore. Instead of only the four steps above, you will have something like:

```
1. X.prepareForReuse()
// inside cellForRowAt
2. X.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(imageA)
// after download finishes 
2.1 X.imageView.image = downloadedImage

// at this point the cell is configured for displaying the content for imageA
// and later you reuse it for displaying the content of imageB
3. X.prepareForReuse()
// inside cellForRowAt
4. X.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(imageB)
4.1 X.imageView.image = downloadedImage
```

In this case, because of concurrency, you could end up with the following cases:

- 1, 2, 2.1, 3, 4, 4.1: Everything is displayed properly (this will happen if you scroll slowly)
- 1, 2, 3, 2.1, 4, 4.1: In this case the first image finishes downloading after the call to reuse the cell finishes, so the old image will be displayed (wrongly) for a short period of time while the new one is downloaded, and then replaced.
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 2.1, 4.1: Similar to the case above.
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 4.1, 2.1: In this case the old image finishes downloading after the new one (there is no guaranty the downloads finish in the same order they started) so you will end up with the wrong image. This is the worst case.

For fixing this problem, let's turn our attention to the problematic piece of code inside the `loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString` function:

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
            // this is the line corresponding to 2.1 and 4.1 above
            self.image = downloadedImage
        }
    })

}).resume()
```

As you can see, you are setting `self.image = downloadedImage` even when you aren't displayed the content associated to that image anymore, so what you need is some way to check if that's still the case. Since you define `loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString` in an extension for `UIImageView`, then you don't have much context there to know whether you should display the image or not. Instead of that, I propose to move that function to an extension of `UIImage` that will return that image in a completion handler, and then call that function from inside your cell. It would look like:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
            completion(cachedImage)
        }

        //No cache, so create new one and set image
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    completion(downloadedImage)
                }
            })

        }).resume()
    }
}

class FeedItem: UITableViewCell {
    // some other definitions here...
    var postImageURL: String? {
        didSet {
            if let url = postImageURL {
                self.image = UIImage(named: "loading")

                UIImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(url) { image in
                    // set the image only when we are still displaying the content for the image we finished downloading 
                    if url == postImageURL {
                        self.imageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                self.imageView.image = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

// inside cellForRowAt
cell.postImageURL = postImageURL
```

Comment: This definitely sounds like the solution I am looking for and your prognosis of the problem sounds accurate. I have two small problems though, for the extension (self.image = ...) I get "'image' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level" and in the FeedItem class (UIImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(url) { image in) I'm getting the error: "Instance member 'loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString' cannot be used on type 'UIImage'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?" which sounds like it is related to the first problem.

Comment: Sorry, the extension was supposed to define a static function. I update the code to include that change and also added how the code should look like inside the extension method.

Comment: Thank you, one more error: UIImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(url) { image in... gives error : "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: My mistake, `postImageURL` in the cell definition should be of type `String` instead of `URL`. Fixed in the code

Comment: Great, it runs error free but can you explain your usage? At the moment I'm getting "Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString'" How do I change my UIImageView to an UIImage? Do I just change the outlet?

Comment: In the code you can see that I use it by calling `UIImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString`, not `UIImageView. loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString`

Comment: Gotit thanks but when I put cell.postHeroImage.UIImage.image.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(postImageURL) then it tells me : "Static member 'loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIImage'" So how do I solve this since I can call an instance of UIImage but not the class itself?

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because this looks like the most thorough solution. I'm still struggling with the comment above if you know how to solve that, that would be great.

Comment: Inside the `cellForRowAt` function you only need `cell.postImageURL = postImageURL`, at that point the `didSet` corresponding to postImageURL inside the `FeedItem` will be executed and the image will be loaded properly. You can get rid of the call `cell.postHeroImage.UIImage.image.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(postImageURL)` since you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deal with this problem will be by using  `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` for loading downloaded images from the cache and `tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)` for removing the image from the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedItem", for: indexPath) as! FeedItem
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.postTitle.text = postArray [indexPath.row].postTitle
    cell.postDescription.text = postArray [indexPath.row].postBody

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let feedCell = cell as! FeedItem 
    if downloadImages.count > 0 {
        cell.postHeroImage.image = downloadImages[indexPath.row]
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let feedCell = cell as! FeedItem 
    cell.postHeroImage.image = nil
}
```

If you are using CocoaPods, I would strongly recommend using **Kingfisher** for dealing with image downloads for your project

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and cached the image based on the image URL itself and use it when load the table with that url.

Let's say you have an array of image URLs load the number of rows with this array and download image should be mapped to indexPath and cached. Later you can use it based on the indexPath with array.

The issue which you are facing is not sync row with mapped data in downloaded image. As TableViewCell deque and reuse the cell.

Comment: So if I understand your response correctly I should only show the cached image and never the image that just loaded? Makes sense, but how would I do that using my "loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString" function?

Comment: http://www.ericd.net/2009/05/iphone-caching-images-in-memory.html#top

Answer (score 1):

That is because `tableView` reuses it cells. So one cell could be responsible for multiple images with different `url`s.

So there is a simple solution for this:

Instead of passing the reference to the reusable cell, you should pass the `IndexPath`. It's value type and would not reuse.

Then when you have got your image from the async task, you can ask the `TableView` for the actual cell with `.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` function.

So, get rid of this line:

```
cell.postHeroImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(postImageURL)
```

and replace it with a function that takes the actual indexPath and maybe a reference to the `tableView`.

Watch [**this WWDC 2018 session**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/?time=988) for more information. It's about `UICollectionView` but same as `UITableView`.

Also you can get the `indexPath` and the `tableView` from the cell itself like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59108366/5623035) but make sure you done it **BEFORE** calling the async function.

Answer (score 0):

you are using in your `cellForRowAt` function with a reusable cells, although the cell is ever load and unload information, we both know that when a picture is downloading, the downloading is not quick, you need download your images in any function except `cellForRowAt`. for example

if you have an array of urls

```
let arrayImages = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
let downloadImages = [UIImage]()
var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

extension for UIImage

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func downloaded(from url: URL, completion: ((UIImage,String) -> Void)?) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global().async() {
                completion?(image,url.absoluteString)
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func downloaded(from link: String, completion: ((UIImage,String) -> Void)?) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

code for your view

```
override func viewWillAppear()
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    for url in arrayImages 
    {
       dispatchGroup.enter()
       let imageDownloaded = UIImage()
       imageDownloaded.downloaded(from: url) { (image, urlImage2) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.downloadImages.append(image)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }     
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
         tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedItem", for: indexPath) as! FeedItem
    cell.delegate = self
    if downloadImages.count > 0 {
        cell.postHeroImage.image = downloadImages[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.postTitle.text = postArray [indexPath.row].postTitle
    cell.postDescription.text = postArray [indexPath.row].postBody

    return cell
}
```

if you have any doubts, please tell me. I will hope that this can help you

Comment: Hi @Andres , although what you say in your proposed solution makes sense to me - I cant seem to get it to work in my code? Keep in mind I already only dispatch the images after they have loaded in my UIImageView extension.

Comment: well, I propose you something, I changed the way that the image is download, check out my answer and tell me if you have doubts.

Comment: Still not working for me I'm afraid but I added my Firebase code, hopefully that makes it a bit easier?

Comment: what is `post` in your `retrievePosts`function? if its a struct or something, please, show the code. 
I think that you want to retrieve data, for have an object array, it's correct?

Comment: sorry yes, I just edited the code to include my custom class named Post

let post = Post()